# Bean class in Java EE 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

While conventional JavaBean classes must conform to a set of standards, including:
1) It must define a zero argument default constructor
2) It must implement a Serializable interface.

the Bean class defined in Java EE 7 is quite different. Almost any Java class can be a bean, as long as its lifecycle is managed by a Web container. Here is the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-basic003.htm#GJEBJ

It says a CDI Bean has the following attributes:

```
A (nonempty) set of bean types

A (nonempty) set of qualifiers (see Using Qualifiers)

A scope (see Using Scopes)

Optionally, a bean EL name (see Giving Beans EL Names)

A set of interceptor bindings

A bean implementation
```

These attributes are very abstract to me. And the following example is one CDI bean. This is just a regular class which implements a super simple interface. Can someone use the following example to explain the "attributes" requirements listed above? Thanks

```
@RequestScoped
public class MessageB implements Message {
public MessageB() { }

@Override
public String get() {
    return "message B";
}
```

}

Comment: where does it say attributes?

Answer (score 1):

*A (nonempty) set of bean types*: **Message**

*A (nonempty) set of qualifiers (see Using Qualifiers)*: **@Default** (see last source code at the end of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-basic006.htm#GJBCK) page)

*A scope (see Using Scopes)*: **@RequestScoped**. If no scope is provided then **@Default** is applied

*A set of interceptor bindings*: empty set in your case

*A bean implementation*: **MessageB**